# Understanding Skein relations

Tags: topology, quantum-computer

I'm just studying some concepts in the topology, but I cannot figure out totally how Skein relations work.

in the following I've one example:

[image]

which tries to relate Reidmeister II to the Skein relations. In the right hand side of the relation, why the coefficients ordered like that? I just cannot link it with Skein relations defined here:

[image]

Please tell me what are the steps.
Thanks